# Select cells to the last filled row in a named range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range, for example GroupedCells: Sheet1$C$1,Sheet1$D$1,Sheet1$G$1. I would like to get the data  in these rows to the last filled row.

Code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("GroupedCells").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

It doesn't work as it selects only Sheet1$C$1 to Sheet1$C$10 for example. I need it to select  Sheet1$C$1: Sheet1$C$10, Sheet1$D$1: Sheet1$D$10, Sheet1$G$1: Sheet1$G$10. How do i do it using Namedrange.

Comment: Do you want the last row for which all of these columns are filled? Or the last row for which at least one of these columns is filled?

Comment: Do you want to include the situation in which there are empty cells within your range?

Comment: i want the first row to last row of these columns

Comment: But do you want from the first row until the last row in which all three columns are filled? Or from the first row until the last row in which at least one of these columns is filled?

Comment: i want from the first row to last row in which all the three columns are filled.

Comment: Are the three columns filled in different rows?

Comment: @FaneDuru, nope,the three columns are filled to the same number of rows

Comment: Then, test my answer code, please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rngU As Range
    Dim ar As Range
    Set rngDB = Range("GroupedCells")

    For Each ar In rngDB.Areas
        If rngU Is Nothing Then
            Set rngU = Range(ar, ar.End(xlDown))
        Else
            Set rngU = Union(rngU, Range(ar, ar.End(xlDown)))
        End If
    Next
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rngU.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: instead of resize(10), i want the data to the last row in the column

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub testSelectNamedRange()
      Dim rng As Range, lastRow As Long, rng1 As Range
      Dim rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, arrRng As Variant
       Set rng = Range("GroupedCells")  'put the named range in a variable
       arrRng = Split(rng.address, ",") 'extract each cell addres from the above range
       lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row 'determine the last row of the first rng column
       Set rng1 = Range(Range(arrRng(0)), Cells(lastRow, Range(arrRng(0)).Column)) 'create a range for each column
       Set rng2 = Range(Range(arrRng(1)), Cells(lastRow, Range(arrRng(1)).Column))
       Set rng3 = Range(Range(arrRng(2)), Cells(lastRow, Range(arrRng(2)).Column))
       Union(rng1, rng2, rng3).Select 'select the union of the above created ranges
End Sub
```

Comment: it only selects Sheet1$C$1:Sheet1$C$10

Comment: @: But, what range does your "GroupedCells" name keeps? Isn't it "C1:G1", as I understand from your question? Is your range a discontinue one?

Comment: it keeps it as C1,D1, G1

Comment: @lakesh: It is a little more complicated for a discontinuous range, but I will adapt the code in two, three minutes...

Comment: @lakesh: Adapted the code to select discontinuous range... Please, let me know if it works as you wish...